# Python - Loop inside loop of two files with regex

Tags: python, regex, file, loops

Im trying to create a loop in order to check two files and compare with regex if a specific field matches.

```
avi file
TVShowName.S01E01.W.DVDRip.XviD.avi
TVShowName.S01E02.W.DVDRip.XviD.avi
TVShowName.S01E03.W.DVDRip.XviD.avi

srt
tvShowName.S01E01.episodename.DVDRip.XviD.srt
tvShowName.S01E02.episodename.DVDRip.XviD.srt
tvShowName.S01E03.episodename.DVDRip.XviD.srt
```

Without a loop I can match the file and make the magic happen. Although when I use the loop it only reaches the first line.

```
TVShowName.S01E01.W.DVDRip.XviD.avi
TVShowName.S01E01.W.DVDRip.XviD.srt
```

Code:

```
f1 = open('avi', 'r')
f2 = open('srt', 'r')
f3 = open ('merge', 'a')
for avi in f1:
    m = re.search(".*([Ss][0-20].[eE][0-24].)+.*", avi )

    for sub in f2:
        n = re.search(".*([Ss][0-20].[eE][0-24].)+.*", sub )
        if m.group(1) == n.group(1):

            str_avi = str(m.group(0))
            #print str_avi

            ext_srt = str_srt.split('.')
            ext_avi = str_avi.split('.')

            #print  ext_avi
            #conv_str = str(m.group(0))
            merge = str_avi.replace(ext_avi[-1],ext_srt[-1])  
            print merge
            f3.write(merge)
f3.close()
```

Comment: Can you add some input of your files ?

Comment: You don't define `str_srt` in the piece of code provided

Comment: The Output it is already on the post mate. I am still not sure where Im get it wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the output you wanted. I can't add comments because I don't have enough reputation points.

```
import glob
import re
avifiles = []
srtfiles = []
for afile in glob.glob('*.avi'):
    avifiles.append(afile)
for sfile in glob.glob('*.srt'):
    srtfiles.append(sfile)
#f1 = open('avi', 'r')
#f2 = open('srt', 'r')
f3 = open ('merge', 'a')
for avi in avifiles:
    m = re.search(".*([Ss][0-20].[eE][0-24].)+.*", avi )

for sub in srtfiles:
    n = re.search(".*([Ss][0-20].[eE][0-24].)+.*", sub )
    if m.group(1) == n.group(1):

        str_avi = str(m.group(0))
        str_srt = str(n.group(0))

        ext_srt = str_srt.split('.')
        ext_avi = str_avi.split('.')

        #print  ext_avi
        #conv_str = str(m.group(0))
        merge = str_avi.replace(ext_avi[-1],ext_srt[-1])  
        print merge
        f3.write(merge+"\n")
f3.close()
```

Comment: I wrote again the script. It is working now. I am just making some adjustments and I post it.

Answer (score 0):

I made the follow code and it seems working. My next step is add more video extentions. But it should be easy.
Thank you guys fot the helping!

```
import re, os, sys, itertools

str_avi = ''
split_avi = ''
global zzz
lista_avi = []
lista_srt = []
lista_final = []
os.chdir('.')
f1 = os.listdir(".")


for full in f1:
    avi = re.search(".*([Ss][0-9].[eE][0-9].)+.*(...$)", full )
    if avi:

        if avi.group(2) == 'avi':
            lista_avi.append(avi.group(0))
        elif avi.group(2) == 'srt':
            lista_srt.append(avi.group(0))
        else:
            pass
    else:
        print "Nenhum Arquivo localizado!"      

for f,b in itertools.izip(lista_avi,lista_srt): 
    data_avi = f.split('.')     
    data_srt = b.split('.')
    data_regx_avi = re.search(".*([Ss][0-9].[eE][0-9].)+.*(...$)", f )
    data_regx_srt = re.search(".*([Ss][0-9].[eE][0-9].)+.*(...$)", b )
    for x in lista_srt:
        data_regx_srt = re.search(".*([Ss][0-9].[eE][0-9].)+.*(...$)", x )
        if data_regx_avi.group(1) == data_regx_srt.group(1):
            print 'Arquivo video:', data_regx_avi.group(0)
            print 'Arquivo sub:  ', f.replace(data_avi[-1],data_srt[-1])
            #lista_final.append(f.replace(data_avi[-1],data_srt[-1])) 
            xx = f.replace(data_avi[-1],data_srt[-1])
            os.rename(x, xx)
```